# Polyglossia-Babelshorthands for quotes ignores csquotes formatting

Tags: formatting, polyglossia, csquotes

For a larger book project containing two languages I use `polyglossia` with the babelshorthands option. For the German style quotes I used the shorthands "` (opening) and "' (closing). This worked perfectly.

Now that I got the layout rules from my publisher I have to change all quotation marks to guillemets. I did this by loading `csquotes` with the `german=guillemets` option.

But only with partial success. All biblatex references correctly use guillemets now, also all quotes that are envoked with `\enquote`. But all quotations using the mentioned shorthand still use the normal German style of quotation marks.

Alas, I do not have the extra two months of time to replace all the shorthands with a correct `\enquote` command. How do I tell `csquotes` to interpret the shorthands according to the default setting? Or where else do I find this configuration?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=22.2cm,paperwidth=14cm,bottom=2.11cm,top=1.6cm,right=1.6cm,textwidth=10.8cm,textheight=18.49cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{3.5mm}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage{polyglossia}%
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={-clig}}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}
\addfontfeature{Language=German}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

Quotation with enquote looks like \enquote{this}.

Quotation with babelshorthands  looks like "`this"'. Which is not intended.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get it to work with `\defineshorthand` (but I had to trim down your example, for I miss stuff in my system which was required to build it).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{URW Palladio L}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\defineshorthand{"`}{\openautoquote}
\defineshorthand{"'}{\closeautoquote}

\begin{document}

Quotation with enquote looks like \enquote{this}.

Quotation with babelshorthands also looks like "`this"'. Which is what is sought for.

\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! The clue was to invoke ``\defineshorthand`` after ``polyglossia`` package is loaded. Stupid me. Could you add that to your answer? (And I'll delete this utterly wrong sentence from my question).

Comment: @shevek You probably have to call it after `babelshorthands` has been specified.